# Spring automatic type conversion is not working for string to Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my request handler method in web mvc I have done something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{day}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String dateValidation(
            @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-mm-yyyy") Date day) {
        System.out.println("date is " + day);
        return "date";
    }
```

As per the spring docs says [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion)

it will automatically convert **String** to **Date** type.

Why I need to add Initbinder in my controller as

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        // Although spring says it is automatic
        binder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("dd-mm-yyyy"));
    }
```

Am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Because `dd-mm-yyyy` isn't a by default supported pattern.

Comment: ok if I put a default pattern then InitBinder is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing date in the custom pattern so the Spring don't know how to parse it to the correct date object. So that's why you need to add custom formatter, that will Spring use to convert your pattern into the `Date` object.

Comment: what is default pattern or default pattern vary Locale to Locale?

Comment: Its ok ,no issue ,BTW your answer helped a lot

Comment: Spring Reference (chap. 7.7) says: By default, date and time fields that are not annotated with @DateTimeFormat are converted from
strings using the the DateFormat.SHORT style. If you prefer, you can change this by defining your
own global format.